# I have a flexbox container with 2 children. one of them is wider than the parent container, how can I add overflow to it?

Tags: css

I want the container with the "`overflow`" class to be able to have `horizontal scroll` since it is wider than its direct parent. how can I do it?

```css
html, body{
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
}

.container{
   display:flex;
   background:yellow;
   width:100%;
   height:100px;
   max-width:100%;
}

.container div{
  border:1px solid red;
}

.sizeSmall{
  width:200px;
}

.overflow{
  width:4000px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="sizeSmall"></div>
 <div class="overflow"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: You cannot add overflow to it but overflow to its parent container. You add overflow to the container not to the overflowing content

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can you give me an example please? it is not clear to me.

Comment: add overflow to the container an flex-shrink:0 to the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need an inner container inside the one you want to scroll:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sizeSmall {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.overflow {
  width: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sizeSmall"></div>
  <div class="grow">
    <div class="overflow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-x: scroll;` to `.container` and use `flex-shrink: 0;` on the flex children.

You can also accomplish this without `flex-shrink` using `min-width` on the `flex` children.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sizeSmall {
  width: 200px;
}

.overflow {
  width: 4000px;
}

.container>div {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sizeSmall"></div>
  <div class="overflow"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I need overflow x in `.overflow` only

Comment: @yavgz Then I would go with Pete's answer and use `min-width: 200px;` on `.sizeSmall`.

Comment: @yavgz or `flex-shrink: 0;` on `.sizeSmall` works the same.